# Java Apache POI Unable to Get Code Working Correctly

Tags: java, apache-poi

Edit - thanks for responses.  Have made changes and as suggested found the problem was a NOW on empty rows.

I am writing a program that loads various excel sheets and provides an output based on certain criteria.  See code below.  My problem is that the code does not write or save to the DISPLAY sheet.  I realise the code below is not particularly neat but have copy pasted to check if I can get anything to save.  If I comment out everything within the loop and try to write to the cell at the end before I save, it works and shows in the sheet.  If I don't comment out the data formatter part it doesn't work even when trying to write to cell just before the part where I am saving output file.  I am guessing the problem is caused by the data formatter, but I can't work out why.

```
public void checkForChanges()  {
  try {
        FileInputStream fsIP = new FileInputStream("Change.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook fWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP);
        HSSFSheet recipeSheet = fWorkbook.getSheet("RECIPE STEPS");  
        HSSFSheet fromSheet = fWorkbook.getSheet("FROM FORMAT");
        HSSFSheet toSheet = fWorkbook.getSheet("TO FORMAT");
        HSSFSheet displaySheet = fWorkbook.getSheet("DISPLAY");
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            DataFormatter recipeFormatter = new DataFormatter();
            HSSFRow recipeRow = recipeSheet.getRow(i);

            HSSFCell recipeCellsColumnA = recipeRow.getCell(0);
            String recipeCellValueColumnA = recipeFormatter.formatCellValue(recipeCellsColumnA);
            System.out.println(recipeCellValueColumnA);

            HSSFCell recipeCellsColumnB = recipeRow.getCell(1);
            String recipeCellValueColumnB = recipeFormatter.formatCellValue(recipeCellsColumnB);
            System.out.println(recipeCellValueColumnB);


            DataFormatter fromFormatter = new DataFormatter();
            HSSFRow fromRow = fromSheet.getRow(i);
            HSSFCell fromCells = fromRow.getCell(0);
            String fromCellValue = fromFormatter.formatCellValue(fromCells);
            System.out.println(fromCellValue);

            DataFormatter toFormatter = new DataFormatter();
            HSSFRow toRow = toSheet.getRow(i);
            HSSFCell toCells = toRow.getCell(0);
            String toCellValue = toFormatter.formatCellValue(toCells);
            System.out.println(toCellValue);

            if (recipeCellValueColumnB.equals("YES") && !fromCellValue.equals(toCellValue)) {     
                System.out.println("PUT VALUE FROM 'TO FORMAT' COLUMN A ROW I INTO 'DISPLAY' SHEET CELL COLUMN B ROW I");
                System.out.println("PUT VALUE FROM 'RECIPE STEPS' COLUMN A ROW I INTO 'DISPLAY' SHEET CELL COLUMN A ROW I");
                Row row = displaySheet.createRow(0);
                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("TEST");                                            
            } else if (recipeCellValueColumnB.equals("YES") && fromCellValue.equals(toCellValue)) {
                System.out.println("SET CELL IN 'DISPLAY' SHEET COLUMN A ROW I TO '' ");
                System.out.println("SET CELL IN 'DISPLAY' SHEET COLUMN B ROW I TO '' ");
                Row row = displaySheet.createRow(0);
                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("TEST");
            } else if (recipeCellValueColumnB.equals("NO")) {
                System.out.println("PUT VALUE FROM 'TO FORMAT' COLUMN A ROW I INTO 'DISPLAY' SHEET CELL COLUMN B ROW I");
                System.out.println("PUT VALUE FROM 'RECIPE STEPS' COLUMN A ROW I INTO 'DISPLAY' SHEET CELL COLUMN A ROW I");
                Row row = displaySheet.createRow(0);
                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("TEST");  
            }else if (recipeCellValueColumnA.equals("Step Name") && recipeCellValueColumnB.equals("Always Compare?")) {  
                System.out.println("SET CELL IN DISPLAY COLUMN A ROW I TO 'REQUIRED STEPS'");
                System.out.println("PUT VALUE FROM 'TO FORMAT' COLUMN A ROW I INTO 'DISPLAY' SHEET CELL COLUMN B ROW I");
                Row row = displaySheet.createRow(0);
                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("TEST");  
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File("Change.xls"));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(output_file);
        fWorkbook.write(output_file);
        fWorkbook.close();
        bos.close();
        output_file.close();


    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Sorry for any poor explanation, it's late and I'm tired and frustrated!

Thanks

Comment: Do what @Stephen C suggests. You will probably find that `fromSheet.getRow(i);` returns `null` for totally empty rows since those are not stored into the file. So `fromRow.getCell(0);` will throw a `NullPointerException` then. So you need to check whether `fromRow` is `null` before further working with it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is this:

```
catch(Exception e)
  {

  }
```

This is saying "don't tell me about any exceptions".  This is exception squashing ... and it is horrible, and lazy, and just plain wrong.

Somewhere in your code there is *probably* something that is either throwing an exception directly, or causing POI (or something) to throw an exception.  That's a bug.  But your horrible exception squashing is **throwing away the evidence** that will allow you to identify and then fix the bug.

> I am guessing the problem is caused by the data formatter, but I can't work out why.

It could be many things ... including something daft like an NPE or a passing an out-of-range index of an incorrect filename.

Solution:

- Get rid of the try catch, and allow the exceptions to propagate to the caller.
- In the caller (or further up the stack) handle *unexpected* exceptions by printing or logging a stacktrace and causing the application to fail.
- Run the modified program.
- When it fails (at it probably will), read the exception message and stacktrace and work out what the underlying problem is; i.e the problam that your horrible exception squashing is hiding.

Then remember to NEVER squash all exceptions like that, in Java or in any other programming language.

(It is *sometimes* OK to squash a specific exception in a specific context ... but only after carefully analyzing the code to ensure that that you won't squash other (unexpected) exceptions at the same time.)